# So many mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I've developed an app using a cross platform technology, phonegap/cordova. The problem I found is that there are still some devices it doesn't work properly on. It's practically impossible to test on all the available mobile devices out there.

How are you guys managing so that you ensure confidence that your apps work on a majority of mobile devices out there?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do to check this is test your application on as many devices/emulator-configurations as possible.

If you are concerned if you app will look good on all Smart-Phones and Tablets, you can create multiple Android-Emulators to test it.

More information about how to optimize your app for multiple screens can be found [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

And you should put this in your manifest

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true">
    </supports-screens>
```

Answer (score 1):

Traditonal way:
Test as much as possible, release in production and fix when user reports.

Newer options:
https://appthwack.com
http://xamarin.com/test-cloud

Look for mobile cloud testing on google